# Access Raspberry pi from remote network

Tags: raspbian, owncloud

I am trying to make a Cloud NAS Server with my Pi. I am using ownCloud to access my server currently. But the problem is it works in the local network but not in the remote network as I don't want to use port forwarding for that.

I posted the same question on the Raspberry Pi forum and someone suggested to me  to look at Weaved. I have seen some of the Weaved tutorials. What I learnt is I can control my Pi through Weaved but does it allow me to store files on my Pi via Weaved? And I can add multiple users?

Or is there any other way through which I can access my server via ownCloud and use Weaved to access ownCloud from the remote network?

Comment: Without port forwarding, you'd have to go though a central server somewhere else on the internet.

Comment: I have used Weaved and it is the most straightforward solution, when connected to your Pi using Weaved I think it would be possible to access your files. Maybe give FileZilla a look? @AndroidDev is correct in that your only other options involve port forwarding.

Comment: Weaved is a great solution to use for your RPi. I have created a small CLI for interfacing with Weaved, which returns your connection information without the need to log onto weaved.com. It can be found here :) https://github.com/mikeres0/weaved-cli